# How implement circle Floating Action Button in Nextjs + Tailwindcss?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, floating-action-button

I want to create two identical menus on the same page, one located in the top left corner and the other in the bottom right corner. I am attempting to create a circular floating action button using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. My code is located in `src/app/page.tsx`. I am using @headlessui/react and @heroicons/react/24/solid to create the buttons.

Here is my current code:

```js
'use client'
import { Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import {
  Bars3Icon,
  HomeIcon,
  PhotoIcon,
  PuzzlePieceIcon,
  TicketIcon,
  WrenchIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
import { Fragment } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const menus = [
    { name: 'Home', icon: HomeIcon },
    { name: 'Gallery', icon: PhotoIcon },
    { name: 'Games', icon: PuzzlePieceIcon },
    { name: 'Ticket', icon: TicketIcon },
    { name: 'Settings', icon: WrenchIcon },
  ]

  return (
    <div className="relative flex h-screen w-screen bg-cyan-500">
      {/* semi circle for first menu */}
      <div className="absolute left-4 top-4 h-52 w-52 rounded-br-full bg-amber-500"></div>

      {/* first menu */}
      <Menu as="div" className="absolute left-4 top-4 ">
        <Menu.Button className="flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-black/20 hover:bg-amber-900/70">
          <Bars3Icon className="h-10 w-10 text-white" />
        </Menu.Button>
        <Transition as={Fragment}>
          <Menu.Items>
            {/* please implement semi circle  */}
            {menus.map((menu, index) => (
              <Menu.Item key={index}>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full border-2 ${
                      active
                        ? 'border-amber-900/70'
                        : 'hover:border-amber-900/70'
                    }`}
                  >
                    <menu.icon className="h-8 w-8 text-white" />
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            ))}
          </Menu.Items>
        </Transition>
      </Menu>

      {/* second menu */}
      <div className="absolute bottom-4 right-4 h-52 w-52 rounded-tl-full bg-amber-500"></div>

      {/* semi circle */}
      <Menu as="div" className="absolute bottom-4 right-4">
        <Transition as={Fragment}>
          <Menu.Items>
            {/* please implement semi circle  */}
            {menus.map((menu, index) => (
              <Menu.Item key={index}>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <button
                    className={`flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full border-2 ${
                      active
                        ? 'border-amber-900/70'
                        : 'hover:border-amber-900/70'
                    }`}
                  >
                    <menu.icon className="h-8 w-8 text-white" />
                  </button>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            ))}
          </Menu.Items>
        </Transition>
        <Menu.Button className="flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-black/20 hover:bg-amber-900/70">
          <Bars3Icon className="h-10 w-10 text-white" />
        </Menu.Button>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the current output of the program [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b50g.png). I want the menu items to be arranged clockwise. For the first menu, I would like the first item to be positioned at 3 o'clock and the last item at 6 o'clock. Similarly, for the second menu, I want it to start from 9 o'clock and end at 12 o'clock.

Can someone assist me with modifying my code to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I just tested in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dwu7uy?file=src%2FHome.jsx) and it already seems to look like the provided [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b50g.png). Did you mean you wanted the "start" and "end" labels to be shown?

Comment: When the menu button is clicked I want Item Menu to form a Semi Circle, I mean the label 'start' for the first index of Item Menu and 'end' the last index of Item Menu